# How can I move last child in front of first child

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to change my navbar logo from the end to the start of the navbar when it's in tablet view so I can have the logo img on top of the screen

This is what I have for code. I tried using flex and order for the items but can't seem to get it to work

```css
@media (max-width: 1050px) {
  .navbar {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .navbar a:first-child {
    order: 5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="services.html">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Product</a>
  <a href="#">Vision</a>
  <a href="#">Features</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="index.html"> <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="Great Idea! Company logo."></a>
</div>
```

And nothing happens, if someone can help me and explain to me what I am doing wrong that'd be great

Comment: your logo is the last-child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [order is 0 by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order#Specifications), we should change it to something below 0, like `-1`.

Also, you said in your question that you need to move the last child to the front, so you should use `:last-child`, not `:first-child`.

```css
@media (max-width: 1050px) {
  .navbar {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .navbar a:last-child {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="services.html">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Product</a>
  <a href="#">Vision</a>
  <a href="#">Features</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="index.html"> <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="Great Idea! Company logo."></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahhh okay, I used first-child because I assumed I was trying to replace "the" first-child to the the logo number, 

But why is it -1 and not 5?

Comment: @OscarPacheco It is -1 because the others have `order:0` by default. Setting it below 0 will put it in front of the other elements